# Automount drive on startup

Tags: mount, hard-drive, steam, automount

I have an internal HDD with all my Steam games loaded on it. Everytime I boot my pc I have to open the HDD in the File Manager. Otherwise Steam does not recognise it and I have to manually add the Steam library back again.
Is there a good fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

Lacking details on your setup, I can only give general guidance.

All you have to do is edit (as root) `/etc/fstab` and add the partition you wish to mount.  For details, options, etc, check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions